# how to reshape in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

Dataframe looks like below

[image]

```
날짜  역번호 역명  구분  a   b   c   d   e   f   ... k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t

2008-01-01  150 서울역(150)    승차  379 287 371 876 965 1389    ... 2520    3078    3495    3055    2952    2726    3307    2584    1059    264

2008-01-01  150 서울역(150)    하차  145 707 689 1037    1170    1376    ... 1955    2304    2203    2128    1747    1593    1078    744 406 558

2008-01-01  151 시청(151) 승차  131 131 101 152 191 202 ... 892 900 1154    1706    1444    1267    928 531 233 974

2008-01-01  151 시청(151) 하차  35  158 203 393 375 460 ... 1157    1153    1303    1190    830 454 284 141 107 185

2008-01-01  152 종각(152) 승차  1287    867 400 330 345 338 ... 1867    2269    2777    2834    2646    2784    2920    2290    802 1559
```

I have dataframe like above.  which I want to a~t reshape `(a~t, 1)`

I want to reshape dataframe like below

```
날짜      역번호 역명  구분          a

2018-01-01  150 서울역 승차  379

2018-01-01  150 서울역 승차  287

2018-01-01  150 서울역 승차  371

2018-01-01  150 서울역 승차  876

2018-01-01  150 서울역 승차  965

....

2008-01-01  152 종각  승차  802

2008-01-01  152 종각  승차  1559
```

like `df = df.reshape(len(data2)*a~t, 1)`

how can i do this ??

Comment: try looking into "melt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# A sample dataframe with 5 columns
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,5))
# Firsts 0, 1 will be retained and rest of the columns will be made as row
# with their corresponding value. Finally we drop the variable axis
df = df.melt([0,1],value_name='A').drop('variable', axis=1)
```

[image]

is converted to

[image]